# RCP Feature based Application deployment: Unable to acquire application service

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to build my feature based RCP Product it runs perfectly while configured in eclipse but the deployment fails. When opening the eclipse.exe it gives me this error (in an error log)

```
!SESSION 2012-10-10 12:17:59.689 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_07
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-10-10 12:18:02.303
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Any suggestions? what am I doing wrong with the building process?

Comment: How are you building it?  Do  you have a `.product` file, and use the Export link in the product editor?

Comment: Yes, and also use the delta pack .. it has worked before but then it was when using a plug-in based product

Comment: Could you please update your question to describe your feature?  How do you include all of the plugins necessary to get `org.eclipse.core.runtime` working?